# Как узнать размер L3 кэша AMD/Intel

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Как можно узнать размер кэша L3 на различных процессорах, используя серию вызовов `__cpuid(ex)`?

```
void __cpuidex(int *regs, int leaf, int attempt)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, attempt
        mov eax, leaf
        cpuid
        mov esi, regs
        mov [esi], eax
        mov [esi + 4], ebx
        mov [esi + 8], ecx
        mov [esi + 12], edx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить альтернативный вариант получения L3Cache из SMBIOS (без вызова __cpuid(ex) ):

Получить структуру ProcessorInformation, в ней есть поле L3CacheHandle, по которому из структуры CacheInformation можно получить размер кеша.

[Спецификация SMBIOS](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios)

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не почитать спецификацию?

Запрос на "amd cpuid specification"  даёт ссылку http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/25481.pdf

Зачем читаем L3:

```
CPUID Fn8000_0006_EDX L3 Cache Identifiers
bits from:to
31:18 L3Size: L3 cache size. Specifies the L3 cache size is within the  following range:  
    (L3Size[31:18] * 512KB)   L3 cache size < ((L3Size[31:18]+1) * 512KB). 
17:16 reserved
15:12 L3Assoc: L3 cache associativity. L3 cache associativity. See Table 4. 
11:8 L3LinesPerTag: L3 cache lines per tag. 
7:0  L3LineSize: L3 cache line size in bytes. 

table4
0h L2/L3 cache or TLB is disabled.
1h           Direct mapped.
2h           2-way associative.
4h           4-way associative.
6h           8-way associative.
8h           16-way associative.
Ah          32-way associative. 
Bh          48-way associative. 
Ch          64-way associative. 
Dh          96-way associative. 
Eh          128-way associative. 
Fh          Fully associative
```

По идее что-то такое

```
function getL3Size(){
 int regs[4];
 __cpuidex(&regs,0x8000,6); 
 return (((unsigned long)regs[0]) >> 18) * 512 * 1024;
 }
```

Comment: По идее  или точно?

Comment: Согласен, на ответ не катит. Для intel - таблица + запрос __cpuidex, и ещё один запрос что б отделить intel от AMD и возможно от других. Хочу сдвинуть вопрос с места.